# A serialization exception while starting up Apache Ignite 2.7 on Net Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ignite

I've coded up an Ignite .Net service in C# which is running on Linux/NET Core 2.2. Now I'm trying to consume it in a .Net Framework web application.

```
    Ignition.ClientMode = true;

    var igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
    {
        IgniteHome = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\bin\")
    }; 

    using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(igniteCfg))
    {
        var services = ignite.GetServices();
        IQuoteGeneratorContract proxy = services.GetServiceProxy<IQuoteGeneratorContract>("QuoteService");
        quotes = proxy.GenerateQuotes(quoteRequestMapped);
    }
```

However, I am getting a strange exception when calling Ignition.Start:

```
    Type 'Domain.ElasticCachedReference`1[[Domain.Partner, Utility.Click.Domain, Version=3.10.56.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'Utility.Click.Domain, Version=3.10.56.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

Stack Trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList argsToSerialize)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage..ctor(IMethodCallMessage mcm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System._AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.Jvm.GetCallbacksFromDefaultDomain()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.Jvm..ctor(IntPtr jvmPtr)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.Jvm.GetOrCreate(IList`1 options)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.IgniteManager.CreateJvmContext(IgniteConfiguration cfg, ILogger log)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
   at Domain.ServiceAdapters.QuoteServiceAdapter.GenerateQuotes(IEnumerable`1 products, Tender tender, Dictionary`2 customCPs) in C:\Users\alexavrutin\Projects\utilityclick\src\Domain\-Logic\ServiceAdapters\QuoteServiceAdapter.cs:line 54
   at Domain.Tender.Submit(Object shardingKey, TenderOptions tenderOptions, Boolean isSkipRecalcManualQuotes, Dictionary`2 customCPs, Boolean forceGenerateSMEQuotes) in C:\Users\alexavrutin\Projects\utilityclick\src\Domain\-Logic\Tender.cs:line 616
```

I need to say that the exception message is absolutely correct: The type Domain.ElasticCachedReference is really not marked as [Serializable]. However, I am not using this type in any Ignite service and not storing it in Ignite cache. I am just trying to run Ignite in the same application where this class is defined and used, and after all, I am just starting Ignite and not yet calling any service or running a distributed closure.

I've reviewed the Ignite source code and suspect that the exception is thrown in a Net Framework method and is likely to be related to how a type is instantiated by Activator rather than to Ignite itself. However, I am wondering how I can do to prevent this exception from occurring? Thank you!

I'm using the following software on the machine where the client is running: 
Windows 10 Pro,
Visual Studio 2017, 
C# 7.1,
Net Framework 4.7.1 with ASP.NET,
Apache Ignite .Net 2.7

Comment: I would imagine that `ElasticCachedReference` is somehow referenced in your service. Can you also share the source of `GenerateQuotes`?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal runnable project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @alamar Thank you for the suggestion. It is unlikely: the service is running on .Net Core in Linux while `ElasticCachedReference` is only present on the client machine running Windows/Net Framework and it targets Net Framework itself. 

I wonder if Ignite is trying to collect and serialize the clases in the neighboring assemblies for the transmission to other nodes? It would be strange as I am running it in the client mode.

Comment: @AlexAvrutin it is quite possible. Can you try to put service into a separate assembly where there's nothing else? Note that for Java Services are not peer loaded at all, but it may be different for .Net.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Thanks for the response, Will do later today or in the first days of Jan. So far I have temporarily worked the problem around by implementing an HTTP endpoint for the service so that I don't have to start Ignite on the client.

Comment: @alamar Tried that, it didn't help. I guess it collects everything loaded up into the current AppDomain, and the assembly containing the class in question is. I tried to set  

PeerAssemblyLoadingMode = Apache.Ignite.Core.Deployment.PeerAssemblyLoadingMode.Disabled

in configuration but it didn't help, either.

Comment: Come to think of it, PeerAssemblyLoading would not put Serializable requirements on types.

Comment: Any hopes for a reproducer project?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay with this. I did try to reproduce the issue on an empty project and was not able to: Ignite started up successfully. However, since the problem still persists in the real project, I will keep investigating this later, probably in early Feb when the other parts of the project have been finished. So far I am using a REST API to communicate with the ignite services so the bug explained above is not particularly pressing. 
Thank you for the follow-up!

Comment: An update: I still could not replicate the error on a new ASP.NET project. So I've referenced the Ignite Core project in the original project (where the exception occurs) and stepped into the Ignite.Net source code. I've noticed that the exception occurs when instantiating the AssemblyResolver in Jvm#GetCallbacksFromDefaultDomain() in this line var resHelp = (AssemblyResolver)defDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(resHelpType.Assembly.Location, resHelpType.FullName)
                .Unwrap();  Not yet sure how to interpret this, keep investigating.

Comment: Also, noticed that defDomain is of the type "System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy". Not sure if it is good or bad but to some extent this explains why the ultimate exception occurs in the remoting routines.

Comment: @alamar You may find the above findings interesting.

Comment: I recommend removing things from your services (and other stuff defined in Ignite configuration) one by one (this might need to be done on server node) until you no longer see the problem. Then last removed thing was the problematic one.

Comment: @alamar Ok, I'll try